# jQuery UI dialog and Ajax POST, JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui, dialog

Is it possible to combine Ajax post with jQuery UI dialog?
And I want to process the ajax reponse in JSON to HTML for showing inside the Dialog box

```
var url = AJAX_URL+requestId+'/'+userId;
// Need to POST the requestId and userId instead of GET

$("body").append("<div id='dialog-modal'>Loading...</div>");
$("#dialog-modal").dialog("destroy");
$("#dialog-modal").load(url).dialog({
    modal:   true,
    title:   "Update Status",
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Update: function() {
            // Do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have put what I have done so far in the code, currently all parameters need to send via URL with the call ("#dialog-modal").load(url); which is actually a GET request, how can i change it to POST?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change it to POST by providing data as an object.

For example:

```
$("#dialog-modal").load(url, {"requestId": requestId, "userId": userId})
```